# FOP batik NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/batik/bridge/UserAgent

Tags: xsl-fo, apache-fop, batik

I do not use maven, or pom or anything. I just have simple test class for testing and I just try to make XSL-FO to PDF conversion and I get this error.
The code is simple:

```
package testing;

import java.io.BufferedOutputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream; 

import javax.xml.transform.Source;
import javax.xml.transform.Transformer;
import javax.xml.transform.sax.SAXResult; 

import javax.xml.transform.Result; 
import javax.xml.transform.TransformerFactory; 
import javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamSource; 

import org.apache.fop.apps.Fop; 
import org.apache.fop.apps.FopFactory; 

import org.apache.xmlgraphics.util.MimeConstants;


    public class test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String pth="C:/Temp/";
        FopFactory fopFactory = FopFactory.newInstance(new File(".").toURI());
        TransformerFactory factory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
        OutputStream out;
        try
        {   
        out = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(new File(pth+"myfile.pdf")));

        InputStream in = new FileInputStream(pth+"everything.fo");

        Source source = null;
        Transformer transformer = factory.newTransformer();
        source = new StreamSource(in);      
        Fop fop = fopFactory.newFop(MimeConstants.MIME_PDF, out);
        Result res = new SAXResult(fop.getDefaultHandler());
        transformer.transform(source, res);         
        } catch (Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();;
        }       
    }
}
```

And this is result:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/batik/bridge/UserAgent
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredConstructors(Class.java:2671)
    at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:3075)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructor(Class.java:2178)
    at org.apache.xmlgraphics.util.Service.providers(Service.java:85)
    at org.apache.xmlgraphics.image.loader.spi.ImageImplRegistry.discoverClasspathImplementations(ImageImplRegistry.java:115)
    at org.apache.xmlgraphics.image.loader.spi.ImageImplRegistry.<init>(ImageImplRegistry.java:79)
    at org.apache.xmlgraphics.image.loader.spi.ImageImplRegistry.<init>(ImageImplRegistry.java:87)
    at org.apache.xmlgraphics.image.loader.spi.ImageImplRegistry.<clinit>(ImageImplRegistry.java:71)
    at org.apache.xmlgraphics.image.loader.ImageManager.<init>(ImageManager.java:64)
    at org.apache.fop.apps.FopFactoryBuilder$FopFactoryConfigImpl.<init>(FopFactoryBuilder.java:381)
    at org.apache.fop.apps.FopFactoryBuilder.<init>(FopFactoryBuilder.java:90)
    at org.apache.fop.apps.FopFactoryBuilder.<init>(FopFactoryBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.fop.apps.FopFactoryBuilder.<init>(FopFactoryBuilder.java:71)
    at org.apache.fop.apps.FopFactory.newInstance(FopFactory.java:143)
    at testing.test5.main(test5.java:37)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.batik.bridge.UserAgent
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 16 more
```

Here are my libs:
[image: My Libs]

What do I do wrong?
As I said I don't use POM, MAVEN etc., just simple java code for testing purpose. I know that there is some dependencies but without POM how I can manage this things?

Here is my FO file:
[everything.fo](https://ufile.io/bgm07)

Answer (score 12):

concerning this trouble I have solved my problem using the last version of batik.

in POM.xml i have this:

```
<dependency> 
<groupId>org.apache.xmlgraphics</groupId> 
<artifactId>batik-bridge</artifactId> 
<version>1.11</version> 
</dependency>
```

Comment: On my side, this error was triggered by Apache POI when I parse some specific PPTx files. It's solved now. thks

Comment: It's 1.14 by now, nevertheless the answer is still a valid solution.